# Laravel Filament list resource relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

I'm using Laravel Filament, and I have hard time to list the resource relations in a way I want.

I have a `Survey` and a `Question` model. A survey can have many question, and a question belongs to a survey. In the `SurveyResource` I want to list the survey's questions in the table, and use survey as just a filter. Also I want to ordering the questions there.

```
return $table
            ->columns([
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('questions.title')

            ])
            ->filters([
                //
            ])
            ->actions([
                Tables\Actions\EditAction::make(),
            ])
            ->bulkActions([
                Tables\Actions\BulkActionGroup::make([
                    Tables\Actions\DeleteBulkAction::make(),
                ]),
            ]);
```

This list the questions in one row, but I want to appear in different rows.

Should I use `RelationManager` or a custom page for this feature?

Comment: You should use a custom page.